# How can i minimize the blurriness after i resize my images?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

My code to resize images is :

```
from PIL import Image


ratio = 0.2
img = Image.open('/home/user/Desktop/test_pic/1-0.png')
hsize = int((float(img.size[1])*float(ratio)))
wsize = int((float(img.size[0])*float(ratio)))
img = img.resize((wsize,hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img.save('/home/user/Desktop/test_pic/change.png')
```

what i have tried is:

The different options other than `.ANTIALIAS` https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize

Adding the parameter `quality` when saving `img.save('/home/user/Desktop/test_pic/change.png',quality=95)`

Converting to rgb `img = img.convert("RGB").resize((wsize,hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)`

the thing is my images are full of small texts in the original image so  really need a good outcome when they're resized to be able to process them further or even read them.

Comment: try `img = img.convert("RGB").resize(wsize,hsize).quantize()`

Comment: Gave this error `ValueError: unknown resampling filter`

Answer (score 0):

Resizing images is no magic - If your image is `4000x3000` and has texts of height `40x30` (per character, individual lines of maybe `6` pixels thickness in it) and you resize it to `0.2` the resulting image is `800x600` and the text characters are `8x6`  with lines of `1(.2)`px in it.

The text lines are very thin lines so they get smutched together with the colors that surround them - regardless of what filter you use to "average" the 
 colors of the vanishing pixels into whats left afterwards.

You can try to sharpen your image *before* you resize it, to make the text stand out more in hope of ganing a sharper result by Bi/Trilin filtering.

You can do the same afterwards to regain some of the contrasts between your smushed text colors and the surrounding pixels - but thats about it. Both will effect the whole picture.

Readup: http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageFilter.html  - has a `Sharpen` filter you can try out.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Patrick's answer, the filters alter the appearance of an image and can cause artifacts in the image after application.  Here are two that I recommend:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

ratio = 0.2
img = Image.open('/home/user/Desktop/test_pic/1-0.png')
hsize = int((float(img.size[1])*float(ratio)))
wsize = int((float(img.size[0])*float(ratio)))
img = img.resize((wsize,hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img.save('/home/user/Desktop/test_pic/1-0.no-filter.png')
img_sharpened = img.filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)
img_sharpened.save('/home/user/Desktop/test_pic/1-0.sharpened.png')

f = ImageFilter.UnsharpMask()
img_unsharp = img.filter(f)
img_unsharp.save('/home/user/Desktop/test_pic/1-0.unsharp.png')
```